# Org-Drill definitions: "drill item", "drill topic", "org topic"?

Tags: org-drill

In this [Overview of org-drill](https://bitbucket.org/eeeickythump/org-drill), what is the difference between "drill item", "drill topic", and "org topic"?

Here is a quote from the "Introduction" section:

> Each **topic** is treated as a "flash card". The material to be remembered
>   is presented to the student in random order. The student rates his or
>   her recall of each **item**, and this information is used to schedule the
>   **item** for later revision.

Here is a quote from the "Writing the questions" section:

> Org-Drill uses **org mode topic**s as '**drill item**s'. To be used as a **drill
>   item**, the **topic** must have a tag that matches the value of
>   org-drill-question-tag. This is :drill: by default.
>
> **Drill item**s can have other **drill item**s as children. When a **drill item**
>   is being tested, the contents of any child **drill items** will be hidden.
>   You don't need to schedule the **topic**s initially. Unscheduled **item**s are
>   considered to be 'new' and ready for memorisation. How should '**drill
>   topic**s' be structured? Any **org topic** is a legal **drill topic** –
>   it will simply be shown with all subheadings collapsed, so that only
>   the material beneath the main **item** heading is visible. After pressing
>   a key, any hidden subheadings will be revealed, and you will be asked
>   to rate your "recall" of the **item**.

The page contains 16 occurrences of "**drill item**", 5 occurrences of "**drill topic**", and 2 occurrences of "**org topic**".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I do not use `org-drill` so I could be wrong. Below is just what it seems apparent to me from reading the [`org-drill` README](https://bitbucket.org/eeeickythump/org-drill).*

It looks like the author is using *drill topic* and *drill item* for the same thing.. And he is referring to *Org headings* as *org topics*.

From the **Simple topics** section, we have this example:

```org
* Item                                   :drill:
What is the capital city of Estonia?

** The Answer
Tallinn.
```

- `* Item` is an *org topic* (*Org heading*) and a *drill topic/item* too (because of the `:drill:` tag, default value of `org-drill-question-tag`).
- `** The Answer` is also *org/drill heading/topic/item* because it also has the `:drill:` tag -- by the virtue of org tag inheritance though.

---

**Bottom Line**

- Any *Level* (headings with asterisk) Org heading with `:drill:` tag is recognized as a *drill question*.
- Nested Org headings under that would be *drill answers*.

*PS: Now you have two new terminologies :)*

Comment: Drill question can be on any level.